# Recommendation Systems User Profile Streaming Data on GCP

Tags: machine-learning, data, recommender-system, google-cloud, google-bigquery

I have a recommendation system that recommends articles to different users. I am planning to provide the recommendations in an off-line fashion. Where I already have a table in BigQuery which has the recommendations and an API call returns the recommendations for each page on the website.

Now I want to have another table called `user_profile` which stores the information about the `user_id|shown|clicked|` articles to the users. This should happen in real-time. I looked into https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/streaming-data-into-bigquery but it has limitations. I cannot write multiple rows into the table at once. Let's say I have 5000 unique users looking at an article once.

Any other suggestion for updating the user_profile table or am I missing something?